# Bitwise shift for unsigned long long type

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

In a c program. I am trying to use the left shift operator on uint64_t variable.

E.g.

```
  // with shift of 24 bits
  uint64_t x = 0;
  x = (((uint64_t)76) << (24));
  Output is: x = 1275068416
  ---------------------------------------------
  // with shift of 32 bits
  uint64_t x = 0;
  x = (((uint64_t)76) << (32));
  Output is: x = 0
```

If I perform left shift till 24 bits then it works fine, but at 32 bits it outputs 0. Whereas what I think is as the size of uint64_t i.e. unsigned long long is 64 bits. So shouldn't it work till the 64 bit shift ?

Comment: What construct do you use to examine the value of `x`?

Comment: I am just printing out the value of x using printf as    printf("....%d\n", x);

Comment: QED, then.. `%d` is working for `int`s. Use "`%llu`"

Comment: Ah, that's just that. To print a value of type `uint64_t` you need `printf("%"PRIu64"\n", x);`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. and  Andrey Chernyakhovskiy ... thanks it works as suggested by both of u :-)

Comment: To be fully correct, `%llu` expects an argument of type `long long unsigned`. Practically speaking, `long long unsigned` is 64-bit on *all* platforms I ever heard of, but theoretically it might be larger, because the language requires that it should be *at least* 64 bit large. `PRIu64` is the macro that's specially meant for `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong format specifier to print the output.  The `%d` format specifier expects an `int`, which apparently is 32-bit on your system.  So passing a 64-bit value (and an unsigned one at that) leads to undefined behavior.

You should use the `PRIu64` macro to get the correct format specifier for an unsigned 64-bit value.

```
printf("%"PRIu64"\n", x);
```

Comment: `%lu` is solely reserved for `unsigned long`. On a Windows machine that's typically 32 bits.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Thanks.  Edit applied.